Adding one careless dot in Scheme code works with one weird result without throwing syntax errors
Recently when I am coding my homework using Scheme language, I carelessly added one dot. Here is one minimal demo:
(define (test value)
  (vector-map 
    (lambda (elem) 
      (cond 
        ((number? elem) 
          (newline).  ; carelessly add one .
          (expt 3 4))
        ))
    value))

(test (vector 3))
; outputs 4, i.e. 4 in (expt 3 4). (verified by changing the corresponding 4 to other numbers)

The actual project is much complexer than the above and uses one code base offered by the teacher. I took some time to find the above careless result by first debugging. But I failed and then I reverted to the history version. After comparison, I found it is that dot causing the weird result.
IMHO here the interpreter will think of ((number? elem) (newline) . (expt 3 4)) as one list. But this is not one normal syntax for cond. So how does the interpreter manipulates with the above program?

There is an implied begin on the condition's value expression, and (begin (newline) . (expt 3 4)) is also 4; it is equivalent to (begin (newline) expt 3 4). (I think; some expert will probably come by and correct me.)

Similar situation to your previous question about weird syntax

@molbdnilo You can always use the interpreter to understand the "standard" representation of a list written in dotted-pair notation, by quoting the list. And indeed evaluating '(begin (newline) . (expt 3 4)) yields (begin (newline) expt 3 4).

@Shawn You are right. Sorry for posting one duplicate question.

@amalloy Thanks. I was trying to find exactly that "trick" but failed.
